# Using the grep search result of a SYSTEMCTL status into a IF CONDITION

Tags: if-statement, grep, conditional-statements, systemctl

First of all, thanks for looking into this!

I am very newbie at bash scripting what I am trying to achieve is:
I currently have to restart some services at my work quite often and I am trying to create a scrip to automatise it, I managed to create everything but I want also to create a conditional where if the systemctl status = inactive then echo "ok, fine, all good" so lets proceed but if not, then echo "re-start will be re-atempted in 10secs"; I am using grep to find the text "active: active (running) or "active: inactive (dead) from the systemctl status on the service (represented by bluetooth.service bellow):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Restarting  bluetooth.service

clear
active_stop="Active: stopped (dead)"    
echo  "This script will RESTART the following service: Bluetooth.Service"
echo -e  "State the REASON for the RESTART: " >> /home/sjadmin/SYS_RESTART/ARCHIVE/sysrestart.log
read -p  "Press ENTER to continue or CTRL + C to cancel"

sudo systemctl stop bluetooth.service |grep active IF [[grep -q=$active_stop]] 

then read -p  "Service STOPPED, please confirm status bellow, press ENTER to continue..."
else read -p "Action failed";

fi

sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service |grep status1="$(Active: active (running))" >> /home/sjadmin/SYS_RESTART/ARCHIVE/sysrestart.log

sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service |grep active

echo  "Service will be RESTARTED in 5 MINUTES, PLEASE DO NOT DISCONECT FROM THE SYSTEM..."

sleep 10s

sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service

read -p "Service RE-STARTED, please confirm status bellow, press ENTER to continue..."

sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service |grep active >>  /home/sjadmin/SYS_RESTART/ARCHIVE/sysrestart.log

sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service |grep active

echo  "System RESTARTED CORRECTLY, please find the log at the SYS_RESTART/ARCHIVE folder"
```

Thanks in advance for all the help and the support! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use `systemctl show <service-name> --no-page` instead of parsing status output:

```
status="$(systemctl show bluetooth.service --no-page)"

status_text=$(echo "${status}" | grep 'StatusText=' | cut -f2 -d=)
if [ "${status_text}" == "Running" ]
then
    echo "It's running"
else
    echo "Not running"
fi

active_state=$(echo "${status}" | grep 'ActiveState=' | cut -f2 -d=)
if [ "${active_state}" == "active" ]
then
    echo "It's active"
else
    echo "Not active"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

systemctl is-active <service>

```
root@freeswitch:~# systemctl is-active dialer
inactive
```